# how to check if there is data in an azure block blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to find an more elegant way of checking to see if there is anything in the blob storage I've created.

I have a service that reads from blob storage. I basically need to be sure that when my service is restarted, it will check if there is anything in blob to read and process before running normally.

I can't seem to find a method that checks if the blockblob is empty. I came up with a way to do this, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant way of doing this:

here is my solution, just check if you were able to download anything. Sure it works..

```
public bool IsBlobEmpty()
{
    string text;
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
        text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        if (text.Length > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When you say `blob is empty`, do you mean if the `file's size is 0 bytes` or `file doesn't contain any data (size may be more than 0 bytes)`?

Comment: the file doesn't contain any data. so, if my service is re-imaged and if there was something written previously to the blob, I want to read that data process it, and then continue as normal.

Comment: In this case (assuming your file size is not zero bytes and contains only white spaces), your approach makes sense. Though you may want to trim the text that you've read so that you're getting rid of leading and trailing white spaces. If the file size is zero bytes, then @jangelfdez's answer makes sense.

Comment: the file would only ever contain a json array, or nothing (if it's never been written to before). so it should only be null or more than 0 bytes.

Comment: In this case, I would go with your approach. As you mentioned in comment to @jangelfdez's answer, there would be 2 calls needed in case file does contain some data - one to find the size and 2nd to read the contents if the file contains data. With your approach you just have to make one call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Azure Storage Blob APIs to get the metadata information of the blob and check for its size - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179394.aspx

Response headers from the server contains a Content-Length property

```
x-ms-meta-Name: myblob.txt
x-ms-meta-DateUploaded: Sun, 23 Oct 2013 18:45:18 GMT
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-lease-state: available
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 23 Oct 2013 19:49:38 GMT
ETag: "0x8CAE97120C1FF22"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
x-ms-version: 2013-08-15
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Oct 2013 19:49
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.
```

Comment: cool! but then you would have to make another call to get the content if it isn't empty..

Comment: You can use the Get Blob call instead if you want and check the headers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179440.aspx 

It gets the metadata and the content

Answer (score 0):

You want to check inside the container. The following code returns the names of the blobs inside the given container. You can tweak the way you want.

```
private readonly CloudBlobClient _blobClient;

public List<string> GetBlockBlobNames(string containerName, 
   string prefix = null)
{
    var names = new List<string>();

    var container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName.ToLower());

    if (container.Exists())
    {
        IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> collection = container.ListBlobs(prefix, true);

        // Loop over items within the container and output the length and URI.
        foreach (IListBlobItem item in collection)
        {
            if (item is CloudBlockBlob)
            {
                var blob = (CloudBlockBlob) item;

                names.Add(blob.Name);
            }
            else if (item is CloudPageBlob)
            {
                var pageBlob = (CloudPageBlob) item;
                names.Add(pageBlob.Name);
            }
            else if (item is CloudBlobDirectory)
            {
                var directory = (CloudBlobDirectory) item;
            }
        }
    }

    return names;
}
```

Comment: So you are just checking if the container exists. but the container can exists  without any blockblob. it's lke checking if the folder exists, not the file. I'm still new at this, I just was amazed there wasn't a simple property on the blob to check this.

Comment: As far as I know we cannot check whether a Container has any Blob. However, in the above code, you use `return collection.Any();` if you want to return Boolean value.